# PERL script as pre-commit hook script in SVN

Tags: svn

My project needs to execute perl program instead of shell script to execute pre-commit hook...how to proceed them....thank you

Comment: You didn't give much in the ways of detail. And, you apparently didn't even look at the `pre-commit.tmpl` hook that comes in Subversion. That gives you an example how to execute a Perl script from the `pre-commit` script.

Answer (score 2):

Subversion will automatically run any script called `pre-commit` on Linux/Unix/Mac or `pre-commit.bat` on Windows.

You can do one of two things:

- Rename your Perl script to `pre-commit` or `pre-commit.bat`. If you're on Linux/Unix, you need to make sure that the first line in the script is something like `#! /usr/bin/env perl`. This will invoke the Perl interpreter when the script is called. On Windows, you can run the `pl2bat` command to turn a Perl script into something that the Windows batch processor can run.
- Most people simply change their `pre-commit` script to execute the Perl script. You can do this by simply putting `perl your.script.name.pl` in the `pre-commit` script itself. If you're on Unix, you can simply put `your.script.name.pl` right in the script, and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Start the perl script from the shell script.

Comment: Don't know why someone dinged this. This is actually the standard way you execute a Perl script as a pre-commit hook. You modify `pre-commit` to execute your Perl script. Heck, the `pre-commit.tmpl` hook has an example of doing just that.

Comment: But why not just make `pre-commit` the Perl script you want to execute?

Answer (score 0):

Invoke the Perl script instead of invoking a shell script.